# Having 2 separate <nav> tags that work independently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get two separate navigation menus to operate independently depending on which button a user clicks on, and show up in the same place (left). I have 2 separate functions, but can only get both buttons to open the same navigation menu (Links 1,2,3 not Links 4,5,6). I can get the second menu to open up, but only if I change the ClassName to topnav instead of sidenav. I have also tried getElementByid, but it does not work either. Thank you for any help.

```
<div class="w3-half w3-container">
    <div id="FloatingBox" class="w3-card-16 w3-round w3-blue-grey w3-animate-opacity w3-animate-bottom" style="font-size:xx-large">
        <p><a title="Personal Information" onclick="w3_openpers()" class="w3-btn-floating w3-card-8 w3-animate-bottom w3-ripple w3-theme w3-red"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> 
            Personal
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-half w3-container">
    <div id="FloatingBox" class="w3-card-16 w3-round w3-blue-grey w3-animate-opacity w3-animate-bottom" style="font-size:xx-large; ">
        <p><a title="Professional Information" onclick="w3_openprof()" class="w3-btn-floating w3-card-8 w3-animate-bottom w3-ripple w3-theme w3-red"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> 
            Professional
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--- Side Navigation Personal--->
<nav id="persnav" class="w3-sidenav w3-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="display:none;z-index:5">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 1</a>     
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 2</a>     
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 3</a>
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_closepers()" class="w3-closenav w3-text-theme w3-text-red" >Close &times;</a>      
</nav>
<!--- Script for Side Navigation Personal--->
<script>
    function w3_openpers() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.width = "20%";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.fontSize = "30px";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.paddingTop = "20%";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.opacity = "1";
    }
    function w3_closepers() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
<!--- Side Navigation Professional--->
<nav id="profnav" class="w3-sidenav w3-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-right" style="display:none;z-index:5">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 4</a>     
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 5</a>     
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link 6</a>
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_closeprof()" class="w3-closenav w3-text-theme w3-text-red" >Close &times;</a>      
</nav>
<!--- Script for Side Navigation Professional--->
<script>
    function w3_openprof() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.width = "20%";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.fontSize = "30px";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.paddingTop = "20%";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.opacity = "1";
    }
    function w3_closeprof() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So you want the one script to work for all the `<nav>`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making it much simpler, by just making one function:

```js
function w3_open(elNum) {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[elNum];
    el.style.width = "20%";
    el.style.textAlign = "center";
    el.style.fontSize = "30px";
    el.style.paddingTop = "20%";
    el.style.display = "block";
    el.style.opacity = "1";
}
function w3_close(elNum) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[elNum].style.display = "none";
}
```

Then you would just call it like:

```
<a title="Personal Information" onclick="w3_open(0)" class="w3-btn-floating w3-card-8 w3-animate-bottom w3-ripple w3-theme w3-red"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

with `w3_open(0)` targeting the first nav, and `w3_open(1)` would target the second.
The same with the closing function.
You can make it even simpler by having a CSS class:

```js
    function w3_toggle(elNum) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[elNum].classList.toggle("w3_open");
    }
```

```css
.w3_sidenav.w3_open{
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  padding-top:20%;
  display:block;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Then you would only need one function, and you would just call it `w3_toggle(0)` to toggle the nav open/closed.

Comment: No problem :D glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Got the tip to change the second script to:

```
    <script>
function w3_openprof() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[1].style.width = "20%";
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[1].style.textAlign = "center";
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[1].style.fontSize = "30px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[1].style.paddingTop = "20%";
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[1].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[1].style.opacity = "1";
}
function w3_closeprof() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[1].style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Works great!

Comment: Lol, i deleted that answer, since that doesn't really work the best, very messy :D

Answer (score -1):

try using getElementsById instead of getElementsByClassName

Comment: That's `getElementById`, fyi

Comment: And no, that isn't really the answer.